# May a student continue a discontinued checkride if the CFI who endorsed them voids that endorsement?

Tags: faa-regulations, logbook-endorsements

#### The Situation

CFI Charlie endorses Student Sara's logbook for a checkride. Sara begins the checkride but discontinues, and receives a letter of discontinuance. So far so good.

Before Sara can reschedule the rest of the checkride, she and Charlie have a disagreement. Charlie has access to Sara's logbook and voids his endorsement by [crosshatching](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/106687.zEBjQe.f1df43ce-a1d9-4df5-b1d9-a1681d4992df.png) the entire text of the endorsement before giving it back to her.

#### The questions

1. Is Charlie's endorsement actually considered void?
2. Sara has the letter of discontinuance in hand. Can she reschedule and complete the checkride without getting a new endorsement?

Comment: Sadly, a true (and very unprofessional) story.  Names have of course been changed.

Comment: Wow that musta been some argument...

Comment: I think CFI Charlie way overstepped his bounds. Nothing in the FAA rules or Circulars talk about revoking endorsements *anywhere*. I've looked.

Comment: I would say that Sara just needs to present the log to her examiner and say "now what", and let the FAA guy sort it out.  What else can she do?

Comment: From what I understand, the CFI, after signing off, has no more supervisory role in the checkride process. Claiming to do so might involve the FSDO.
It has been argued elsewhere that scratching off an otherwise valid signature would be an act of vandalism.
These days however, the CFI needs to register that in a Database with the FAA in leu of an actual signature, which would be the gold standard

lastly, talk to the DPE, if they say yes, continue the checkride, get your licence, and the question is moot.

Comment: I think whether CFIs can generally retract an endorsement is a different question than this one.  A *discontinuance* to a check-ride is simply indicating that the event will be completed in separate sessions, but as far as the checkride status is concerned, it is still open/ongoing.  Think of it like this: what would happen if the CFI barged in the room after the oral was passed and demanded that the student not be allowed to continue the flight portion and verbally retracted her endorsement to take the checkride.  What would happen?

Comment: What was the outcome of this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

The test was discontinued. No reason the DPE would be looking in her logbook as a discontinuance is simply a pause in the testing process. She was eligible to test, she remains eligible to test. If she already told the DPE about this the smart DPE would make a note in her test records explaining what occurred. Once endorsed the applicant is endorsed. If the CFI wants to "revoke" her endorsement I believe it's too late.

Answer (score -1):

The examiner won’t be looking at the endorsement but will look at whether Sara has received the required re-training.

**§61.49   Retesting after failure.**

> (1) The necessary training from an authorized instructor who has
>   determined that the applicant is proficient to pass the test; and
>
> (2) An endorsement from an authorized instructor who gave the applicant
>   the **additional** training.

Before the test a new IACRA form must be submitted and signed by an authorized instructor.

The crossed out endorsement is moot. The issue she faces is whether a new instructor would be willing to endorse her for the checkride after just giving training for the failed portion, or whether they would require more from her.

Comment: To be clear, I'm asking about discontinuance, not failure. Student Sara passed the oral, but elected not to begin the flight portion because the weather was bad that day.

Comment: @SteveV. Sorry, I missed that. Just from personal experience, I did my IFR checkride last month after discontinuing for weather and the DPE did not look at my logbooks again.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine. Thank you for the info!